# Reading in Packages in Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I've created a package in Mathematica but I can't seem to get Mathematica to read it in. The Package is of the form:

BeginPackage["name`"]

(*function[]::usage*)

Begin["`Private'"]

(*functions*)

End[]

EndPackage[]

I saved this file as a .m. The problem is that after I quit the kernel and then try to read in the package using Needs["name`"], I always get a no::cont error. I've tried saving the file in $BaseUserDirectory and $BaseDirectory, but it still give me a no::cont error:

Needs["name`"]
Needs::nocont: "Context \!\(\"name`\") was not created when Needs was evaluated."

I've also tried using the built-in File->Install function in Mathematica but it still gives me the same error. Is there something that I need to change with regards to the context?

Any help is much appreciated.

Thank you,
jm

Comment: Please try to use `Get` to read the package and give it a full file name (with complete path!)  What happens?

Comment: This similar post may help: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18646/363

Answer (score 0):

Write the definitions in "Initialization Cells" when you create the package notebook. Otherwise they will be ignored. This worked for me with Version 9 on OS X. In previous versions it was probably not necessary, but I don't remember any more... :-)

Answer (score 0):

It's because the directory of your package is not in `$Path`. `Needs` only searches the packages in `$Path`, while `Get` can search [subdirectories](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Get.html).